# How do I make my div with a background image and no content show and extend from the top to bottom of the page?

Tags: css, html

I made a div with the float:left; property, min-width:100px; , and min-height:100%;

I also included a working background image, but for some reason the div will not show unless I type in some text.  Even then, the div doesn't follow the full height.

Is there a way to make my div show and stretch to the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could give the root element of your document (html)  and the body a 100% height.

```
html,body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
div {
    float:left;
    min-width:100px;
    min-height:100%; 
    position: relative;
    background: red;
 }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6f5x8/8/

Answer (score 1):

The height of your `div` is relative to its parent element. If you have a wrapper around it, give that a height of 100%. Also make sure your `html` and `body` height are defined.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `display:block` if you dont have any content.  100% height will only work if it has a height to reference in the parents.